# Is it “a company who makes ...” or “a company that makes...”?

Tags: pronouns, who-that

Regarding the fact that a company is made up of people and we use *who* for people, is it proper to use *who* here?

Comment: *who* is also found in writing, though only with a singular, not plural, verb: *who make*.

Comment: "Pectin: List of **Firms who Manufacture** Or Sell Either Dried Or Liquid Pectin" (United States. Bureau of Chemistry and Soils, 1931); "In this chapter, however, subcontractor refers to the second type of company, that is, those **who manufacture** according to the buyers' specifications." (Mark S. Glynn: Business-To-Business Brand Management, 2009); "Mainstream chemical companies **who manufacture** some aroma chemicals as part of their business, e.g. BASF..." (David Rowe: Chemistry & Technology of Flavours & Fragrances, 2009) [emphasis mine]

Comment: As Kris mentioned, *who* gets used, but it looks like *that* is used in this context [much more often](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+company+who+makes%2C+a+company+that+makes%2C+a+company+which+makes&year_start=1935&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A company is normally, but not invariably, treated as inanimate, so it will be *a company **which** makes* or *a company **that** makes*, when the relative clause is integrated (also known as ‘defining’ or ‘restrictive’). When the relative clause is supplementary (also known as ‘non-defining’ or ‘non-restrictive’), it is normally introduced by *which*.

This means that we can say *XYZ Inc. is a company **that** makes high tensile steel* or we can say *XYZ Inc. is a company **which** makes high tensile steel*. But we generally  say *XYZ Inc., **which** makes high tensile steel, has had poor results this year* rather than  *XYZ Inc., **that** makes high tensile steel, has had poor results this year.* Some people claim that you cannot use *which* to introduce an integrated relative clause, but they are wrong.

(There is a further complication with a word like *company*, which is seen variously as singular and plural. For the sake of simplicity, I have treated it here as singular.)

Comment: What about a group?

Comment: @Benyamin Hamidekhoo. It depends on the type of group.